# What security issues are there when accepting skype calls from people I do not know?

Tags: skype

Recently I got a friend request from a person I do not even know and of course he was not in my friends list (I mean the people I have accepted in my skype in order to chat or talk live) and he immediately called me. I didn't answer of course and I blocked him. I changed my privacy settings.  But what security issues are there when accepting skype calls from people I do not know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Theoretically it's possible to exploit Skype's VoIP feature to try to hack your device. Such exploits are relatively rare. In most cases this requires to know your OS precisely, as Skype has different clients (read applications) for different operating systems written in different programming languages which makes creation of universal exploits very difficult unless there's a common *logical* flaw in all the clients.
2. Usual phone fraud - this has nothing to do with Skype, as this affects real world normal phone calls and calls via other instant messengers such as WhatsApp, Telegram, etc.

That's pretty much it.

Comment: My skype name, was unfortunately, public. I have changed that too, now...

Comment: It makes sense to use a nickname which is difficult to guess. Skype users can be discovered by simply enumerating common strings. Disabling calls from strangers is still a good thing to do though personally I don't mind talking to strangers even if they want to scam me :-) Some scammers are genuinely interesting people to talk to.